# Java sound: JAR file truncates .wav

Tags: java, audio, jar, wav

Trying to set up a basic .wav player using Java. In the IDE the sounds and music all play perfectly fine, exported to a jar file only the first 1/10 of a second of the sound is played before cutting off.

The program is looping as it does, it has not exited.

Here is the sound player code:

```
private Clip myClip;
private boolean soundPlayed = false;
private boolean runOnce = false;
private AudioFormat af = null;
private AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
private int size = 0;
byte[] audio = null;
DataLine.Info info = null;

public void loadSound(String fileName) {

    try {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SM.class.getResource(fileName));
        af = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        size = (int) (af.getFrameSize() * audioInputStream.getFrameLength());
        audio = new byte[size];
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af, size);
        audioInputStream.read(audio, 0, size);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(boolean music) {
    try {
        myClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        myClip.open(af, audio, 0, size);
        System.out.println("Size: " + size);
    }

    catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(music){
        FloatControl gainControl = 
                (FloatControl) myClip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            gainControl.setValue(game.data.musvol);
    }
    else{
        FloatControl gainControl = 
                (FloatControl) myClip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        gainControl.setValue(game.data.soundvol);
    }
    myClip.start();
}

public void runOnce(boolean music) {
    if (!soundPlayed) {
        try {
            myClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            myClip.open(af, audio, 0, size);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(music){
            FloatControl gainControl = 
                    (FloatControl) myClip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                gainControl.setValue(game.data.musvol);
        }
        else{
            FloatControl gainControl = 
                    (FloatControl) myClip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            gainControl.setValue(game.data.soundvol);
        }

        myClip.start();
        soundPlayed = true;
    }
```

Comment: You have to wait for the clip to finish playing. When you test in an IDE the IDE does not terminate the JVM running your code when the program ends so the clip can finish. When you run outside of the IDE the JVM terminates as soon as the program exits so the clip does not get a chance to finish.

Comment: the program is still looping when the sound chirps. it has not exited.

Comment: the `read()` method does not guarantee to read all that you ask it to read.  pay attention to the return value.  use a while loop to read all the data that you need.